# how to set textfield size fix macos swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have one textfield "A" with width 150. but whenever I am passing more characters to textfield "A", it is getting overlapped on other textfield "B" characters.

I want textfield "A" to be fixed size and scrollable(mostly right and left).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are Layout and Line Break of textfield A?

Comment: I didnt used autolayeouts. Is it not possible without auto-layouts?

Comment: What are `Layout`, `Uses Single Line Mode` and `Line Break` of textfield A in the Attributes Inspector in IB?

Comment: Layout = Truncates, 
Uses single Line Mode = Unchecked, 
Line Break = Truncate Trail

Comment: You can fix the size with layout constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Auto-Layeout in your storybook. **Set fixed width, trailing space and leading space** to your text field.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the Auto-Layeouts to my textfields and I have followed below steps:

1) Selected the label.

2) Go to attributes inspector.

3) Select 'Line Breaks' and choose an option Truncate Tail

4) now I can see the text without overlapping with another textField.

**Note**: But still I am not able to view/Scoll the full text.

Answer (score -1):

Just found this piece of code. It might help you

```
    scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
    textView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
    textView.isHorizontallyResizable = true
    textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
    textView.textContainer?.containerSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
```

Comment: Is `textView` a `NSTextView` or a `NSTextField`?

Comment: Yes. is it a 'NSTextField' or 'NSTextView'? I am using storyboard so is there any way to fix that using storyboard? @Ole